# IntelliJ for Java: view as object by default

Tags: java, intellij-idea, debuggervisualizer

I have a class which extends Collection.  It adds a few fields to maintain some state, then implements the Collection methods I want.

When debugging, IntelliJ shows instances of this class in the Variables window will show the class as "Collection". This view isn't acceptable, since it doesn't show me my interesting members.

I can right-click on the item in the Variables window and have it show as "Object", and that gets me my own fields in the window. Unfortunately, I have to do this every time I debug -- and and sometimes more than once, depending on how I move around the scope of my program.

How can I make IntelliJ persist my choice to show my class as Object rather than as Collection?

Answer (score 2):

1)you can right-click in the Variables windows or Watches windows then click the "Customize Data views" item.

2)do not select "enable alternative view for Collections classes" item.